# multiple table join to generate report counts

Tags: sql-server-2008, inner-join

I am trying to generate a report that will display data from 3 tables as follows:

```
    SELECT  B.datepoll, B.clientID, B.badTerm, A.FullQuery, 
    B.badMessage, C.clientNAME, E.CURRENT_TERMS
    FROM BadTerms AS B INNER JOIN
    QueryTERMS AS A ON B.badTerm = A.QUERIES INNER JOIN
    Clients AS C ON B.clientID = C.clientID INNER JOIN
    ( 
      SELECT CLIENTID,COUNT(QUERIES) AS CURRENT_TERMS FROM QueryTERMS  WHERE 
      clientID = 'XXXXXX' GROUP BY CLIENTID) E ON 
      E.CLIENTID = A.CLIENTID
      WHERE  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), B.datepoll, 120) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)) 
      AND (B.clientID = 'XXXXXX')
```

Basically what should be displayed is for a given datepoll, display all badTerms, fullQuery, badMessage, clientID, clientName and total terms. The clientID is common among all 3 tables and queries is common among BadTerms and QueryTerms.

I have everything fine except for the total count. It should only appear once and be the total queries in the QueryTerms table not the BadTerms table.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Although not the answer to your question, I suggest you re-think this line: `WHERE  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), B.datepoll, 120) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)) `. Why are you converting dates to a string to use in a filter? Also, this query in its current form will not run as you are missing parenthesis and the like. Perhaps you have copy/pasted it incorrectly? Some table definitions would be good as well.

Comment: I cannot recall the exact reason but I was trying to compare the date portions only and came across this suggestion somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually got it to work now:

```
    SELECT  B.datepoll, B.clientID, B.badTerm, A.FullQuery, 
    B.badMessage, C.clientNAME, E.CURRENT_TERMS
    FROM BadTerms AS B INNER JOIN
    QueryTERMS AS A ON B.badTerm = A.QUERIES INNER JOIN
    Clients AS C ON B.clientID = C.clientID INNER JOIN
    ( 
      SELECT CLIENTID,COUNT(QUERIES) AS CURRENT_TERMS FROM QueryTERMS  WHERE 
      clientID = 'XXXXXX' GROUP BY CLIENTID) E ON 
      E.CLIENTID = A.CLIENTID
      WHERE  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), B.datepoll, 120) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)) 
      AND (B.clientID = 'XXXXXX')
```